VBA - Part of code (copy data) is not working every time
I have a problem with my code. In the Sub Action() I want to copy data from cells linked to the database (these are refreshed every project run) to another cells. Unfortunatelly when  I change source data in the database it copies cells after second run of the project, never the first one. When I do it manually, it works great, but when run it with the entire project ->Sub auto_Open() with a worksheet open it works with the second try (cell are updated every time).
Sub auto_Open()
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    Range("A1").Select
   Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("question text'", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "title")
If answer = vbYes Then
Call Refresh
  Else
Call Ready 
 End If
   End Sub

Sub Ready()
Sheets("DATA").Select
End Sub

Sub Refresh()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Call Action
  End Sub

Sub Action()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    Range("av5:av7").Value = Range("au5:au7").Value
    Range("av11:av15").Value = Range("at11:at15").Value
      Range("at20:at35").Value = Range("au20:au35").Value
      Range("ay20:ay35").Value = Range("az20:az35").Value
        Range("bc20:bc35").Value = Range("bd20:bd35").Value
      Range("bg20:bg35").Value = Range("bh20:bh35").Value
       Range("av49:av51").Value = Range("au49:au51").Value
      Range("ax49:ax51").Value = Range("ax45:ax47").Value
          Range("ba53:bc55").Value = Range("ba49:bc51").Value
           Range("bg45:bg49").Value = Range("bf45:bf49").Value
           Range("av53:aw55").Value = Range("av45:aw47").Value
         
          End Sub


I tried to change that code to simple Copy-Paste, but without any progress. Any ideas wthats wrong here?

In Action sub add Application.ScreenUpdating = True before End Sub

The documentation for Workbook.RefreshAll states

Objects that have the BackgroundQuery property set to True are refreshed in the background.

meaning that control will return to the VBA before the query has fully refreshed. That is why it always works the 2nd time, because the 1st call has already refreshed the data.
The solution is to set your queries to BackgroundRefresh = False which will ensure all the queries are fully complete before the call to Action
